# Is i18n possible in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, internationalization

is there a way or a best practice to allow multiple languages for Kafka topics?
Google does not provide much information here, as the results all focus on programming languages instead of i18n.

Thanks!

Comment: why you need this?

Comment: there are several events that contain multilangual descriptions (for consumers with different languages). each consumer would use the description language it needs.

Comment: if there's another way how to deal with this topic, or how to avoid streaming this information in Kafka, please let me also know, I'm happy for every kind of input here...
and I am sure that this is not a "special" requirement no one in this (stackoverflow-)world came accros with by now. I'm just unable to find any information.

Comment: looks like there is no better way except streaming all i18n info in Kafka; you may start a bounty to get some useful advice

Comment: thanks. unfortunately i have not enough reputation by now to do so...